# Countable Hilbert Space Direct Sum is subspace of a vector space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I want to prove that $H:=\bigoplus_{n}^{\infty}H_{n}$ is a vector space, where 
$$ \bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty H_n=\left\{ \underline{x}=(x_1, x_2, \cdots )\in \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}H_n:\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\|x_n\|_n^2<\infty  \right\}. $$
And this seems to be straightforward if one knows that $H$ is a subset of some vector space. I read that it is a subset of the vector space direct sum of the Hilber spaces $H_n$, but that does not seem correct: it seems that we could have elements of $H$ with an infinite number of nonzero $x_i$'s. What is going on?

Comment: Well you need to check the vectorspace axioms. The only not so straightforward thing to check is that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\|x_n+y_n\|_n^2<\infty$ if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\|x_n\|_n^2<\infty$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\|y_n\|_n^2<\infty$. But for this you use the Minkowski inequality. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality

Comment: @MaikPickl Ok, so what I read was wrong? I read it in proof wiki: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Hilbert_Space_Direct_Sum_is_Hilbert_Space

Comment: No, what you read is not wrong. From what you wrote in your last paragraph I suspect that you're confusing two notions of direct sum. There is the direct sum of hilbert spaces: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Hilbert_Space_Direct_Sum And on the other hand the definiton of direct sum of vector spaces: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum

Comment: @MaikPickl I am aware of that. But my confusion remains, probably because of something else: they say that $H$ is a subset of the *vector space* direct sum of Hilbert spaces, but it does not seem like it, because of what I said in the last paragraph.: there are elements of $H$ with an infinite number of nonzero entries, which is not allowed in the infinite vector space direct sum, I believe.

Comment: I see. And I agree. It's the other way around. The vector space direct sum is contained in the Hilbert space direct sum.

Comment: @MaikPickl Ok, so it seems I am forced to check all the axioms. It is not hard, though (as you pointed out)